# Current Location using Location Manager in android studio emulator

Tags: android

I am developing an app that get user current location using location manager or google places api. Using google places api I can get location in both emulator and real devices.

Working with current location in android emulator

For me it returns null.

Note: It was my fault that I didn't set lat and lon on emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, That is something you gotta see, Even Bluetooth Does not work Well.

On to the Question:

1. Start your Emulator.
2. Press the 3 dots at the bottom.
3. Go to the GPS Section.
4. Write the Latitude and Longitude
5. Press Send!

Done!

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault that I didn't give any lat lng in my emulator. Or may be didn't tap on send button or may be internet problem. But there was problem